# Slide Toggle next sibiling div from div inside parent div

Tags: jquery, parent, siblings

I would like to toggle content from  my class "acontent" depending on which "abtn" I clicked on.

My Html:

```
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="abtn">
    <input id="A-1" type="radio" value="A">
    <label class="chars" for="A-1">A</label>
    <div class="char-more">Learn More</div>
 </div>
<div class="acontent">Hello I am content A</div>

 <div class="abtn">
     <input id="B-1" type="radio" value="B">
     <label class="chars" for="B-1">B</label>
     <div class="char-more">Learn More</div>
 </div>
 <div class="acontent">Hello I am content B</div>

 <div class="abtn">
     <input id="C-1" type="radio" value="C">
     <label class="chars" for="C-1">C</label>
     <div class="char-more">Learn More</div>
   </div>
     <div class="acontent">Hello I am content C</div>
  </div>
```

jQuery:

```
  $(".abtn .char-more").click(function(){
      $(this).parent.next(".acontent").slideToggle("fast")
      .siblings(".acontent:visible").slideUp("fast");
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
      $(this).siblings(".char-more").removeClass("active");
  });
```

JSFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/zRqYM/30/

Comment: you are missing `()` in $(this).parent  <--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing **()** for **parent** .. 
Supposed to be **.parent()**

You can also try this using `.closest()`

```
$(this).closest('.abtn').nextAll(".acontent").first().slideToggle("fast")
```